# crystal report database login prompt when using c# and ms-access and dataset

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports

i'm using crystal report and bind a dataset to it in my windowsform application.
my dataset is getting data from a ms-access database and it queries are working cool.
i did not set any login info for my database or dataset or any thing else and still when the report is loading it ask for login.
in login page the server name is the name of my dataset and all other field are empty.
ms-access 2016 - visual-studio 2015 - crystal report 13.0.14

my code

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load("D:/c#/AttendanceApp/AttendanceApp\\CrystalReport_Work.rpt");
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

my query

```
SELECT        p.Personal_FingerId, p.Personal_Name, p.Personal_Family, w.Work_Date, Format(MIN(CDate(w.Work_Time)), 'hh:nn') AS Time_Start, Format(MAX(CDate(w.Work_Time)), 'hh:nn') AS Time_Finish
FROM            (Table_Personal p INNER JOIN
                         Table_WorkUser w ON p.Personal_FingerId = w.Personal_FingerId)
GROUP BY p.Personal_Name, p.Personal_Family, p.Personal_FingerId, w.Work_Date
ORDER BY w.Work_Date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below example, be sure to set your DataSource.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CustomerReport crystalReport = new CustomerReport();
Customers dsCustomers = GetData();
crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);
this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
this.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}

private Customers GetData()
{
string constr = @"Data Source=.\Sql2005;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security = true";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Customers"))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (Customers dsCustomers = new Customers())
            {
                sda.Fill(dsCustomers, "DataTable1");
                return dsCustomers;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I haven't handle crystal report in a while but I'm pretty sure you have to click on the Crystal Report Viewer object in your WinForm and change the property to no login required.  In addition, when referring to a file path use this convention: @"C:\directory\word.txt" for your cryRpt.Load(@"D:\c#\AttendanceApp\AttendanceApp\CrystalReport_Work.rpt").

Comment: there is no "no login" property or something like that for crystal report viewer. and editing the path was not helpful

Comment: I post an example for you to use.  I've use it in the pass and it work. Btw, the path wasn't meant to help but to show you a better way of specifying a path.